# Snapshot failing in a fresh Kilo install

Tags: cloud, openstack

I have a fresh OpenStack Kilo installation.

When I try to create a snapshot from the dashboard or from the nova cli, the snapshot isn't being created.

The local snapshot ends with success, but nova get's a "HTTP 400: Invalid disk format 'None' for image" error when trying to upload the image to glance.

The full log follows at the end.

The question is: Why is this error occurring? And how can I solve it?

**Update:** After some tests, I discovered that Nova uses the Glance API v1 to upload the image. The request done by nova **is right** and both `container_format` and `bare_format` is sent. The request is also complaint with the [Glance v1 API specification](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/glanceapi.html#using-v1-x). However, something is going wrong, as we can see at the following curl command to the Glance API:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'X-Auth-Token: MY_TOKEN_HERE' \
    -H 'x-image-meta-property-image_state: available' \
    -H 'x-image-meta-name: rarytest2-snapshot' -H 'x-image-meta-container_format: bare' \
    -H 'User-Agent: python-glanceclient' -H 'X-User-Id: e45cf65e7ae94cd5aa86341c87308657' \
    -H 'x-image-meta-property-image_location: snapshot' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
    -H 'x-glance-registry-purge-props: false' -H 'x-image-meta-property-ramdisk_id: ' \
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'x-image-meta-property-kernel_id: ' \
    -H 'X-Service-Catalog: []' \
    -H 'x-image-meta-property-owner_id: 2dd6aa6ee0554c0ea5afce27dc63ff3a' \
    -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'X-Roles: _member_,admin' -H 'x-image-meta-size: 1549991936' \
    -H 'X-Tenant-Id: 2dd6aa6ee0554c0ea5afce27dc63ff3a' -H 'x-image-meta-is_public: False' \
    -H 'X-Identity-Status: Confirmed' -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
    -H 'x-image-meta-disk_format: qcow2' \
    http://MY_IP_HERE:9292/v1/images/3b3cdac1-d76c-48f2-8150-0977d8720684
```

The expected behavior is update `disk_format` to qcow2 and `container_format` to bare. However, it doesn't occur.

For some strange reason, if a change the `x-image-meta-disk_format` and `x-image-meta-container_format` headers for `x-image-meta-disk-format` and `x-image-meta-container-format` (it is, changing underscore by hyphens) it works!

**Full log:**

```
2015-05-24 17:50:46.229 2400 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-b6489814-f538-4773-a15d-c1224b5583b7 e45cf65e7ae94cd5aa86341c87308657 2dd6aa6ee0554c0ea5afce27dc63ff3a - - -] [instance: 00652f00-5a32-44ad-8ad6-ac33610236ac] instance snapshotting
[...]
2015-05-24 17:50:58.670 2400 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-b6489814-f538-4773-a15d-c1224b5583b7 e45cf65e7ae94cd5aa86341c87308657 2dd6aa6ee0554c0ea5afce27dc63ff3a - - -] [instance: 00652f00-5a32-44ad-8ad6-ac33610236ac] Snapshot extracted, beginning image upload
[...]
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-b6489814-f538-4773-a15d-c1224b5583b7 e45cf65e7ae94cd5aa86341c87308657 2dd6aa6ee0554c0ea5afce27dc63ff3a - - -] Exception during message handling: <html>
 <head>
  <title>400 Bad Request</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
  Invalid disk format 'None' for image.<br /><br />

 </body>
</html> (HTTP 400)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback))
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 6791, in snapshot_instance
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return self.manager.snapshot_instance(ctxt, image_id, instance)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception.py", line 88, in wrapped
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     payload)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 85, in __exit__
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception.py", line 71, in wrapped
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(self, context, *args, **kw)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 327, in decorated_function
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     LOG.warning(msg, e, instance_uuid=instance_uuid)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 85, in __exit__
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 298, in decorated_function
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 355, in decorated_function
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     kwargs['instance'], e, sys.exc_info())
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 85, in __exit__
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 343, in decorated_function
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 403, in decorated_function
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     instance=instance)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 85, in __exit__
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 393, in decorated_function
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     *args, **kwargs)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 3227, in snapshot_instance
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     task_states.IMAGE_SNAPSHOT)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 3257, in _snapshot_instance
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     update_task_state)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1410, in snapshot
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     image_file)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/image/api.py", line 130, in update
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     purge_props=purge_props)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/image/glance.py", line 398, in update
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     _reraise_translated_image_exception(image_id)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/image/glance.py", line 396, in update
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     image_id, **image_meta)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/image/glance.py", line 219, in call
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return getattr(client.images, method)(*args, **kwargs)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glanceclient/v1/images.py", line 329, in update
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     resp, body = self.client.put(url, headers=hdrs, data=image_data)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glanceclient/common/http.py", line 265, in put
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return self._request('PUT', url, **kwargs)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glanceclient/common/http.py", line 227, in _request
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     raise exc.from_response(resp, resp.content)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Invalid: <html>
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher  <head>
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   <title>400 Bad Request</title>
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher  </head>
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher  <body>
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   Invalid disk format 'None' for image.<br /><br />
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher 
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher  </body>
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher </html> (HTTP 400)
2015-05-24 17:51:01.251 2400 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs due to use of both Nginx and Glance API v1.

In short, the explanation is found [at this thread in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-underscores-are-forbidden-in-http-header-names).

Nginx, by default, drops headers with underscores. This is done to:

> prevent ambiguities when mapping headers to CGI variables

Reference: [Nginx - Pitfalls - Missing (disappearing) HTTP headers](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#missing-disappearing-http-headers).

However, headers with underscores are specified in the Glance v1 API.

Reference: [Glance v1 API - Retrieve image metadata](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/glanceapi.html#retrieve-image-metadata).

I also discovered that headers with underscores [are completely valid and complaint with the RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2).

The solution is to add the following line to the nginx config file:

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```